# weird behaviour in python if clause

Tags: python, if-statement, clause

I wrote a simple little rock, paper, scissors game in python and had some difficulties with an if clause, here's the relevant code:

```
def play():
    user = str(input("rock, paper or scissors? Choose one: "))
    print("You chose", user)

    if user == "paper" or "Paper":
        paper()

    elif user == "rock" or "Rock":
        rock()

    elif user == "scissors" or "Scissors":
        scissors()

    else:
        print("Sorry, your choice was not valid, try again please.")
        play()
```

Now, no matter whether I chose rock, paper or scissors, it would always trigger the first condition, leading me to the paper function. I actually already solved it, it was the second condition I put in the if clauses, the "Paper", "Rock" and "Scissors", which I put there for the case people uppercase the first letter. My question is, why did the second condition trigger the first if clause? When I removed all the second strings, it worked perfectly fine, the rock triggered the second condition, the scissors one triggered the third and so on. I hope this is not too confusing. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually a dup of dozens of equivalent questions here. It's unfortunate that it's so hard to search for them.

Comment: This question has appeared so many times before on SO.  If people made their titles more descriptive other people would be able to benefit from their questions and answers.  Instead of "Weird behavior..." maybe "'or' is always returning true in python if statement".  That would be more likely to be fruitful for future Google searches.

Comment: What would be a more helpful title? I'll change it then. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user == "paper" or "Paper"
```

is always true. The `or` operator tests the expressions on either side of itself, and if either is true, the result of the `or` is also true. Your test above checks (up to) two things:

- Is the expression `user == "paper"` true? If so, the whole expression is true, so don't check the second part, because `True or x` is always true regardless of the value of `x`.
- Is the expression `"Paper"` true? And because non-zero-length strings are true in Python, this part is always true.

So even if the first part is false, the second part is always true, so the expression as a whole is always true.

You wanted something like this:

```
user == "paper" or user == "Paper"
```

or, better yet:

```
user in ("paper", "Paper")
```

or, best of all:

```
user.lower() == "paper"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with lists and `in`:

```
if user in ["paper", "Paper"]:
    paper()
```

or using regex:

```
import re
user = 'paper'
if re.match('papers?', user):
    paper()
elif re.match('[Rr]ock', user):
    rock()
```

with regexes you can also do case-insensitive match:

```
import re
user = 'paper'
if re.match('papers?', user, re.I):
    paper()
```

which will match all: paper, PapER, PaperS, ...

Answer (score 1):

you want:

```
if user == "paper" or user == "Paper":
```

Same for the others as well.

If you just put

```
if "Paper":
```

Python evaluates it as `if this_value_is_true`. Same with the code you have basically evaluates to "if user variable equals 'paper' or True" which would always be tue.

Comment: `if user.lower() == 'paper':`

Answer (score 1):

```
if user == "paper" or "Paper":
```

Actually evaluates to:

```
(user == "paper")  or "Paper"
```

i.e (result of user == "paper") or "Paper"

So the 2 possibilities here are:

1. True or "Paper"
2. False or "Paper"

In first case it returns `True` and in the second one it returns `"Paper"`.

As "Paper" is a True value(all non-empty strings are `True`) so this condition is always `True`.

You should use:

```
if user.lower() == "paper"
```

Comment: I don't think `user == "paper"` evaluates to `user == True`.  Rather, `user == "paper"` is true when `user` is `"paper"`.

Comment: @A.E.Drew oh! that was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I know where your problem comes from:

```
if user == "paper" or user == "Paper":
```

That should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if user == "paper" or "Paper":
```

… is parsed as this:

```
if (user == "paper") or "Paper":
```

If `user` actually is equal to `"paper"`, that's `if True or "Paper"`, which is `True`.

Otherwise, that's `if False or "Paper"`, which is `"Paper"`.

Since `True` and `"Paper"` are both truthy, the `if` always happens.